# Adding row to bound datagridview from oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to build `datagridview` that consist from two part 
one part came from database and the other part is collected information about files on local hard disk and show it as one part but I am getting error message that says

> Rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview rows
>   collection when the control is data-bound

**Note:**
knowing That data within `datagridview` will be used later to modifies data on oracle database

I had upload imag for more understanding the first two column are from database

```
private void ListFileToBePatched()
{
    try
    {
        string connstr = "data source=orcl;user id=user;password=pwd";
        string cmdstr = @"SELECT OFFICE_CODE as ""Office Code"",
                                 IP_ADDRESS  as ""Office IP"" 
                            FROM table";

        string[] array = Directory.GetFiles(SBankfilespath, "*.txt");

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdstr, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

            OracleDataReader OraReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            DataColumn OfficeCodecolumn = new DataColumn();
            OfficeCodecolumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            OfficeCodecolumn.ColumnName = "Office Code";
            dt.Columns.Add(OfficeCodecolumn);

            DataColumn OfficeIPcolumn = new DataColumn();
            OfficeIPcolumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            OfficeIPcolumn.ColumnName = "Office IP Address";
            dt.Columns.Add(OfficeIPcolumn);

            DataColumn FileNamecolumn = new DataColumn();
            FileNamecolumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            FileNamecolumn.ColumnName = "File Name";
            dt.Columns.Add(FileNamecolumn);

            DataColumn FullFilePathcolumn = new DataColumn();
            FullFilePathcolumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            FullFilePathcolumn.ColumnName = "Full File Path";
            dt.Columns.Add(FullFilePathcolumn);

            DataColumn DateCreatedcolumn = new DataColumn();
            DateCreatedcolumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            DateCreatedcolumn.ColumnName = "Date Created";
            dt.Columns.Add(DateCreatedcolumn);

            DataColumn Datemodifiedcolumn = new DataColumn();
            Datemodifiedcolumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            Datemodifiedcolumn.ColumnName = "Date modified";
            dt.Columns.Add(Datemodifiedcolumn);

            foreach (string FullFilePath in array)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

                row[2] = Path.GetFileName(FullFilePath);
                row[3] = FullFilePath;
                row[4] = File.GetCreationTime(FullFilePath);
                row[5] = File.GetLastWriteTime(FullFilePath);

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            dt.Load(OraReader);
            DataView view = new DataView(dt);
            DGV_PatchStatus.DataSource = view;
        }
        FileCount.Text = "File Count ( " + DGV_PatchStatus.Rows.Count.ToString() + " )";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: add the row to your `DataTable` and bind it again

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DataTable.NewRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx) method to add the row to your `DataTable`.

```
foreach (string FullFilePath in array)
{
    DataRow r = DT.NewRow();

    r[0] = Path.GetFileName(FullFilePath);
    r[1] = FullFilePath;
    r[2] = File.GetCreationTime(FullFilePath);
    r[3] = File.GetLastWriteTime(FullFilePath);
}
```

Then simply bind the `DT` again as `DataSource`

```
DGV_PatchStatus.DataSource = DT;
```

**EDIT:**

> what I really need is that for each office has list of files

If you have several files for each office-row you should have a look on this [Tree-View-Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/23746/treeview-with-columns) this might really be helpful to achieve your desired results.

Here is also a [Nested-DataGrid-Example](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/13403/fully-functional-nested-datagrid) that might also be of help. Good luck.

Comment: exception 'Cannot find column 0' is zero is the index of datagridview column ? or the name that I had previously name it when created the datagridview ?

Comment: Actually it should be the column index. How many columns has your data table?

Comment: it has 6 columns including those columns came from database.. i was trying to change the index but that wont solve the problem

Comment: @btw I had manually add the column to datagridview is that correct ? or it will be created automatically like when you just bind data from database to datagridview ?  so thers is no need to create them manually ?

Comment: I had upload imag for more understanding the first two column are from database

Comment: Thank you man I had solved the problem was that I should build the datagridview programmatically Not manually I will update the post for code but I found that it does not fit what I want to show data on separated row what I really need is that for each office has list of files so I think I have to make two datagridview main and sub so when I click on row at main datagridview it will list rows files

Comment: @Sam I found 2 links that might be of help for your problem. I think both possibilities should suit your demands. Have a look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

Make Class For your data after reading from db assign data to that object and put object into List afterwards initialize DGV_PatchStatus.DataSource to that list, when you need to add new row simply add data object to that list and re initialize DGV_PatchStatus DataSource

Comment: Please Can you give me example ?